# Error Brakest editor de codigo

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy en el diseño web comenzando con JavaScript pero no se porque me salen esos errores sera que alguien me puede decir el motivo

Comment: Cambialo por const o var

Comment: es que eso no es el problema porque igual esta según es un error del editor pero no se como solucionarlo por favor si alguien es tan amable de decir como puedo repararlo

Comment: Creo que tu editor esta desactualizado y por ende no soporta `ES6` intenta actualizandolo o descargandole una extensiond e javascript que soporte `ES6`, si lo que digo es cierto entonces el error deberia solucionarse unicamente cambiando la palabra `let` por `var` sin embargo no es lo optimo, pues la idea es usar `let` o `const` y nunca volver a usar var.

Comment: Nada no lo puedo solucionar